# Continuous and Discrete summation

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics

I have a continuous curve $f(x)$ say constant in interval $0$ to $P$ and area under the curve is unity.

Alternately, 
 $f(x) = 1/P$ for $ 0\le x \le P$.

So I can calculate $G = \int_{0}^P f(x)sin(x)dx = \frac{1}{p}(1-cosP)$

Assuming, I have $N$ uniformly distributed data points in $0$ and $P$. Now I calculate $f$ in the form of a vector of size $i_p$, by dividing $F$ into  $i_p$ equal bins and represent $f(i) = \frac{n(i)}{N}$ where $n(i)$ is the number of data points falling in $i^{th}$ bin.

Q1. How can I calculate $G$ for this newly formed $f(x)$ discretely? 
Is it something like,

$G = \sum_{i=1}^{i_p} f(i)sin(Q(i)) = f(1)sin(Q(1))+f(2)sin(Q(2))+,...,f(i_P)sin(Q(i_P))$

where $Q(i)$ represents the mean of $i^{th}$ bin.

Q2. If I'm not wrong, the continuous approach is more accurate. So, is there a way to convert the data to a continuous function, especially when data is not uniformly distributed ?

Thanks in advance.